# How to turn off ALT + numeric keypad ASCII symbol insertion?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse, ascii

I prefer to use the cursor keys on the numeric keypad with <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> turned off. This is fine most of the time but in Eclipse it's causing problems with some of the shortcuts, e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> to move lines around and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> to navigate backwards -- both of these stick in a symbol (e.g. ☻ for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>) after performing the shortcut function.

As a last resort I could either (a) reassign the shortcut keys (don't want to do this as would prefer to use/learn the standard ones) or (b) use the mini cursor keys (not keen on this as prefer to have <kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd>/<kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd> underneath my fingers without jumping my hand around).

Is it possible to turn off the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+numpad shortcut for inserting ASCII characters? (I'm using Windows 7.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Autohotkey to remap, e.g., <kbd>NumpadLeft</kbd> to <kbd>Left</kbd>, which should remove any of the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad</kbd> side-effects.

```
; For Alt + key (with NumLock OFF)
NumpadIns::Ins
NumpadEnd::End
NumpadDown::Down
NumpadPgDn::PgDn
NumpadLeft::Left
NumpadClear::
NumpadRight::Right
NumpadHome::Home
NumpadUp::Up
NumpadPgUp::PgUp
NumpadDel::Del
```

Comment: This allowed me to do things like use "Alt-Left/Right" as "Delete Word Left/Right" is VS Code, without also introducing junk characters into the editor.
This is a great solution as long as you don't require non-num-pad and num-pad keys to be distinguishable.  
It also still allows the use of the Alt-n-n-n character generation, simply by turning NumLock on before Alt-n-n-n-ing what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think AutoHotkey can solve the problem, [have a look here](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm).